# Index/Match issue

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

Surely for you it is very easy to solve the problem I have but since I am starting, I don't know how to fix it. I attach the file. What I want is for you to return the price of the units where the highest number of the week corresponds and the reference that I pass on. The formula that gives me an error in VBA is:

```
ultimoPrecio = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("VENDIDOS").Range("C:C"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(referencia & ultimaSemana, Sheets("VENDIDOS").Range("A:A") & Sheets("VENDIDOS").Range("D:D"), 0), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Also note using `Index/Match` like that, as a formula anyways, requires it to be entered as an array function